# Location and Nature of "*-doc" Documentation?

Tags: apt, software-installation, documentation

While installing software using `apt`, I am often offered "software-doc" as a recommended adjunct to install. Presumably this provides some documentation for the software. For example, when installing `mit-scheme`, I am offered `mit-scheme-doc` as a recommended additional install.

I usually do opt to install the documentation, only to never see or hear from it again! Where does the "*-doc" documentation go, what is it's nature, and how do I tap into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/mit-scheme-doc/filelist `mit-scheme-doc` installs documentation.

You can also see this list by

```
dpkg -L mit-scheme-doc
```

If you open `/usr/share/doc/mit-scheme-doc/html/index.html` in a browser, you'll be able to read it.

There are also some `pdf` files in `/usr/share/doc/mit-scheme-doc/pdf` directory available.

Regarding other `-doc` packages, you can check what they install by

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

Generally documentation is installed to `/usr/share/doc` directory.